# Why does curl localhost provide expected output but navigating to ec2 public IP does not using nginx?

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2

I have been stuck trying to get nginx started up on my ec2 instance. All I have done is install nginx and seems to be running as expected within the server.

Running `curl localhost` serves the default nginx file as expected. Navigating to the public IP, I just get a **site can't be reached error (IP refused to connect)**.

From my understanding, the inbound rules have also been setup correctly. I have not changed any of the configuration files from nginx as I just want to test that it is working. Everything is left as default. Anyone have any ideas as to why this is occurring? Thank you so much. [image]

[image: Inbound]

`ss -lntp`
[image]

Comment: What does `ss -lntp` tell you? Is nginx listening at localhost only? If yes, is there a firewall configured in the instance? Can the instance reach the internet?

Comment: @berndbausch I've attached `ss -lntp`. Nginx is the default configuration so it's listening to `port 80` and `[::]:80`. I've run a ping and seems like the server is reaching the internet no problem.

Comment: Can you reach the external IP from outside with ssh or curl? Can the instance `curl google.com`?

Comment: @berndbausch I can curl google from the instance but can't curl the instance public IP from outside.

Comment: How about ssh? Can you also add ICMP to the security group and try `ping`? If it also doesn't connect,  something is wrong with the external IP and its association with the instance. In other words, you would need to troubleshoot the AWS config.

Comment: I can ssh into the instance using the pem key and private IP. Seems like I can ping the private ipv address, is that what you meant?

Comment: Can you ssh or ping to the **external IP**? I am trying to make you test whether there is connectivity from the internet to your instance.

Comment: Where is the public IP? I don't see it anywhere.

Comment: @berndbausch So turns out, it was my computer blocking that ip address for some reason. It was working fine all along on other devices. I checked flushed my iptable and restarted my computer and it is working as expected. Thank you guys for helping me debug.